# GTK (GTK#) Window created event?

Tags: gtk, gtk#

Is there an event equivalent to WinForm's `Load`, that is called when the GUI window is actually created (not the constructor)? I am using GTK# and this library has no documentation and it is quite different from plain GTK, so it is hard for me to get information from the plain GTK documentation. I tried to guess the event by trying the following code but none of them worked.

```
    protected override void OnRealized()
    {
        base.OnRealized();
        Debug.WriteLine("realsed");
    }

    protected override void OnActivate()
    {
        base.OnActivate();
        Debug.WriteLine("act");
    }

    protected override void OnShown()
    {
        base.OnShown();
        Debug.WriteLine("shown");
    }

    protected override void OnStateChanged(StateType previous_state)
    {
        base.OnStateChanged(previous_state);
        Debug.WriteLine("state");
    }

    protected override bool OnDrawn(Context cr)
    {
        return base.OnDrawn(cr);
        Debug.WriteLine("drawn");
    }

    protected override bool OnWindowStateEvent(EventWindowState evnt)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("win state");
        return base.OnWindowStateEvent(evnt);
    }

    protected override void OnScreenChanged(Screen previous_screen)
    {
        base.OnScreenChanged(previous_screen);
        Debug.WriteLine("screen");
    }
```

Comment: Have your tried the "default-activated" event associated with a GTK window?  In the GTK#/mono documentation it is known as the "Gtk.Window.DefaultActivated" event.  In the .NET documentation it looks to be the "Form.OnActivated" method.

Comment: @CraigSchulstad I tried override the `OnDefaultActivated` method or add a handler to the `DefaultActivated` event; none of them worked. And that gave me an idea and I tried adding a handler to the `Shown` event. That worked. So, overridden `OnShown` never gets called but I get the `Shown` event... weird.

Comment: Well, if it works, I guess go with it.

Comment: OnShown is the closest parallel event you're looking for. When you say they didn't work, what do you mean exactly? Did you call base.OnShown () from inside your override? If you don't then the base OnShown would not be executed, only yours, and that means the form wouldn't be shown. If you're not doing this then this may be why adding another event handler to the Shown event would work but the override didn't?